# Связать расширения yii-user и eauth

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. Имеется связка yii-user + rights. Пытаюсь прикрутить eauth.

Проблема: как из eauth использовать авторизацию yii-user? Т.е. чтобы авторизация использовалась yii-user. Но данные по сути получались из eauth. Пробовал просто записывать "фейковые" аккаунты в таблицу users, чтобы расширение брало его оттуда. В итоге пользователь получит полноценный аккаунт на сайте без нужды ввода логинов и паролей и регистрации. Записывал при первом входе в таблицу, "придумывал" уникальный логин и пароль и передавал в класс авторизации UserIdentity из yii-user. НО! Получается, что юзер может зайти поменять логин - это нестрашно, я найду его в таблице по имени сервиса и id на этом сервисе, которые я храню в таблице. Страшно то, что он поменяет пароль и я его не буду знать, т.к. в таблице хэш от пароля. В итоге не смогу передать в UserIdentity.

Как все же их связать? Чтобы авторизация проходила через eauth, но в коде использовался UserIdentity из yii-user.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, сделал костыль: 
Использовал соц. сеть просто для получения данных о пользователе (как здесь, на хэшкоде). После первого входа ему предлагается заполнить профиль, а соц. сеть помогла лишь вписать полученные данные в соответствующие поля. После этого он становится обычным пользователем, как остальные. Просто для следующего входа ему не нужно будет вводить логин пароль.